# Send array of objects by sockets in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets, objectoutputstream

I want to send using sockets in Android an array of objects (objects are of a class that I have defined). 
I was able to send it with ObjectOutputStream first sending the number of objects in the array and then sending object to object, but I want to know if there is any way to send the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and write whole array to ObjectOutputStream. Should work if your objects are serializable

```
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(stream);
os.writeObject(array);
```

Comment: I have serialized class, but sending array with elements of that class, when I receive that array is empty.